# How to make a phone call without phone app like google hangout?

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm not going to use Intent to invoke default system Phone App, such as Google Hangout. Can we make a call or receive a income call inside our own app rather than system phone app?

Comment: no, you can't. The app has to have at least system permissions (be a system app) to do this.

Comment: @belle rian, hey Dude, you should read this link it may help you https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can do that with the help of a VOIP account. Try over internet you can find lot of VOIP providers and you just have to create an account and use the given instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides an API that supports the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP). This lets you add SIP-based internet telephony features to your applications. Android includes a full SIP protocol stack and integrated call management services that let applications easily set up outgoing and incoming voice calls, without having to manage sessions, transport-level communication, or audio record or playback directly.

Here are examples of the types of applications that might use the SIP API:

- Video conferencing.
- Instant messaging

Check this [Example](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/) or [Example 2](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SipDemo)